# Chrome extension generates cookies, without a visible HTTP request?

Tags: http, cookies, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, httprequest

I installed some chrome extension that pop ups a modal box when I'm on a certain domain.

If I click the button in that box, I see in the Network tab of chrome developer tools, that the extension makes an HTTP Post request to the website.

The request contains some request cookies from the domain: A,B,C,D.
And response cookies from the domain: A,B,C - without D.

When the request is done (and the extension finished doing its "magic"), I discovered that the value of cookie D has changed, even though D was not in the response cookies. I tested it several times.

How is this possible? Can the extension make something in the background that is hidden from the network tab, that will cause the cookie D from the domain to change?

I want to be able to capture and document this Cookie D generation behavior, and don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`chrome.cookies`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) API, a Chrome extension can manipulate the cookies that are stored in the browser without the need to perform an HTTP request. The extension will need the [`cookies` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#cookies) to access this API.

You will not be able to capture, or intercept, the extension's calls to the `chrome.cookies` API.

In addition, through the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API, a chrome extension can modify the request headers, including cookies, which are sent or received without directly changing the cookies which are stored in the browser.  The extension will need the [`webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#webRequestBlocking) to make such changes.

Comment: (1) I thought that cookies that were originally created by a domain, can only be modified by the domain. so is this some kind of an "hack"?  (2) are you saying that the extension may do either one of the two options you mentioned in order to achieve this? (3) What do "permissions" mean what it comes to the user? He just allows the browser to install the extension, right? he doesn't need to enable each permission separately. (4) Is there any way to hinder the cookie modification? (5) can a Firefox/Safari extension do the same to cookies?

Comment: Also, is there any cookie sniffing tool that can capture it, if not chrome dev. tools?

Comment: @rockyraw, 1) Extensions have full control. It is functionality intended to be available to extensions. 2) Extensions can do either/both. `chrome.cookies` makes changes to the stored cookies. `chrome.webRequest` can make changes directly to the web request after the request is initiated, but before it is sent to the server and after the data is received from the server, but before it is processed by the browser. 3) In Chrome, the user is explicitly alerted to some permissions. See [Permission Warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings) for details. (continued)

Comment: @rockyraw, (continued) Explicitly enabling each permission is usually not supported, (each extension could do so). 4) Effectively no. You could write another extension that changes it back, or modify the extension so it does not do so. 5) Firefox definitely. Safari, I have no experience with Safari, but I would expect does give similar capabilities to extensions. 6) It depends on what you mean "capture". The actual call that is made to cause the change can not be captured. However, an extension could be written that detects such changes after they have occurred. (continued)

Comment: @rockyraw, (continued) I am not aware of any particular extension that does so. In general, most people assume that the user has installed the extension so it has permission to do so.  In the cases where an extension is doing something undesired, most uninstall the extension. If you have programming knowledge, you get the source code for most/almost all extensions as part of installing it. You can then look through the source code and make changes. The extension author may, or may not, have released it under a license that permits you to make modifications (common for Firefox add-ons).

Comment: Isn't it against Google policy that an extension will modify cookies?

Comment: @rockyraw, I'm not aware of that being the case. If there was such a policy, then I would expect it to be mentioned on the [chrome.cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) page, or for that API not to exist. There appear to be many Chrome extensions that change cookies, which argues against there being such a policy. What gave you the impression that there was such a policy?

Comment: An extension that can do that needs host permissions for the page. This generates a warning for the user that it can "Read and modify your data on {list of websites}". And believe me, an extension can do _much worse_ than modify cookies with a host permission.